# Uber API returns 404 no_partner_for_user with valid token

Tags: uber-api

I have a valid oauth token retrieved from the Uber API for a driver account. When I hit this endpoint:

`curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXX" https://api.uber.com/v1/partners/me`

I'm returned with:

`{"meta":{},"errors":[{"status":404,"code":"no_partner_for_user","title":"The user does not have a partner account."}]}`

My colleague can hit the same endpoint with another valid token for the same driver and successfully receives account data.

**edit**

Just confirming that the account we've authed is absolutely definitely definitively a driver account.

Answer (score 1):

The user does not have a partner account, so it looks like a rider authed and that is the token you are using.

Comment: We've definitely quadruple checked that the authed account is a driver.

Comment: If you make a request to /v1.2/me endpoint do you get a profile?

Comment: Nope, I get: `{"message":"This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: profile, request.delegate.tos_accept, request.delegate","code":"unauthorized"}` which I think is because the token was authorised through the driver api?

Comment: Can you dm @uberdevlopers the details so we can investigate?